# Software & Updates screen is blank

Tags: update-manager

I am running Ubuntu 20.04

Software & Updates screen is blank when opened.

[image]

Does anyone know how to start the Software & Updates GUI from the command line?

Then I could run `pgrep -fl` to check for any orphaned process.

```
root@mail:~# apt show software-properties-gtk
Package: software-properties-gtk
Version: 0.98.9.3
Priority: optional
Section: gnome
Source: software-properties
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Michael Vogt <michael.vogt@ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 456 kB
Depends: gir1.2-goa-1.0 (>= 3.27.92-1ubuntu1), gir1.2-gtk-3.0, gir1.2-snapd-1 (>= 1.42), libgtk3-perl, python3, python3-dateutil, python3-distro-info, python3-gi, python3-requests-unixsocket, python3-software-properties (= 0.98.9.3), software-properties-common, ubuntu-drivers-common (>= 1:0.2.75), dconf-gsettings-backend | gsettings-backend, python3:any
Recommends: gnome-keyring, gnome-session-bin | xfce4-session | mate-session-manager
Task: ubuntu-desktop-minimal, ubuntu-desktop, xubuntu-core, xubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop-core, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-budgie-desktop
Download-Size: 64.0 kB
APT-Manual-Installed: no
APT-Sources: http://mirror.fsmg.org.nz/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: manage the repositories that you install software from (gtk)
 This software provides an abstraction of the used apt repositories.
 It allows you to easily manage your distribution and independent software
 vendor software sources.
 .
 This package contains a GTK+ based graphical interface.

N: There are 2 additional records. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

Comment: It is called `software-properties-gtk`

Comment: Interesting, it works from the command line but not from the applications menu? Not sure what is happening there but if you give this as an answer I will mark it as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Regarding the problem, which version of Ubuntu are you running? It would also be useful to know the version of software & updates (it can be seen using `apt show software-properties-gtk`).

Comment: I have added the information to my question.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it using `sudo apt reinstall software-properties-gtk`? It that still doesn't work, you could try to reinstall also its dependencies using `sudo apt-cache depends software-properties-gtk | grep '[ |]Depends: [^<]' | cut -d: -f2 | tr -d ' ' | xargs sudo apt reinstall -y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [called](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/all/software-properties-gtk/filelist) `software-properties-gtk`.

Answer (score 1):

I ran `pgrep -fl software-properties-gtk` to see if there was any orphaned process.

It returned

```
root@mail:~# pgrep -fl software-properties-gtk
60976 software-proper
934092 software-proper
```

I then did `pkill -f software-properties-gtk` to kill the orphaned processes.

The Software & Updates GUI now successfully launches from the applications menu.